# Having trouble amking if statement within loop work in coffeescript

Tags: loops, if-statement, coffeescript

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this Javascript

```
  for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    if (listItems[i] === window.location.pathname)
      return i
  }
```

that I want to turn into coffee script.  So I tried

```
if window.location.pathname in [listItems[i]] return i for i in [0...listItems.length]
```

but upon running this, I get the error “SyntaxError: [stdin]:77:3: unexpected if”.  What is the right way to translate this JS?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to say [`listItems.indexOf(window.location.pathname)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to use a return in an if-statement on the same line, you should use the "then" keyword.
Secondly, your code logic seems off. What you'd want is something like

```
for i in [0...listItems.length]
   return i if listItems[i] is window.location.pathname
```

It's also a lot easier to read than one convoluted line :-)